# Excel Formula average without blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a row of values and want to find the average of the first 3, not counting blank cells. Example:

```
  A      B  C      D  E  F  G
 12  blank  8  blank  7  9  4
```

The average of the first 3 non-blank cells should be 9, but I can't find a formula that will calculate this for me. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

In **A2** enter:

```
=IF(A1="",0,1)
```

and in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(OR(B1="",SUM($A$2:A2)=3),0,1)
```

and copy across.  Then in another cell enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((1:1)*(2:2))/3
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [AVERAGE](https://superuser.com/questions/915547/excel-formula-average-without-blank-cells) function. According to the formula [syntax and usage](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/AVERAGE-function-7f473887-4818-4212-b85f-474a5be67b8a) for Excel's AVERAGE function:

> If a range or cell reference argument contains text, logical values, **or empty cells**, those values are ignored; however, cells with the value zero are included.

The formula `=AVERAGE(A1:E1)` returns `9`:

[image]

Comment: Well, if it will always be the case that `A1`=12, `B1`=blank, `C1`=8, `D1`=blank, and `E1`=7, then the OP doesn't need a formula; he knows that the answer is 9.  I think the point is that the OP doesn't know in advance which cells will have numbers and which will be blank.  So, if `B1` has a number it (as well as `A1` and `C1`), then the desired result is `AVERAGE(A1:C1)`, and your answer yields an incorrect result.

Comment: The OP clearly stated *I can't find a formula that will calculate this for me*.  Like any Excel user, he needs the correct formula *and* proper application of the formula (e.g. what range to average) to produce his desired result.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

Brute force:
The average that you want can be computed by:

```
=IF(COUNT($A1:$C1)=3, AVERAGE($A1:$C1),
 IF(COUNT($A1:$D1)=3, AVERAGE($A1:$D1),
 IF(COUNT($A1:$E1)=3, AVERAGE($A1:$E1),
 IF(COUNT($A1:$F1)=3, AVERAGE($A1:$F1),
 IF(COUNT($A1:$G1)=3, AVERAGE($A1:$G1), "oops")))))

(Single-line version:)
=IF(COUNT($A1:$C1)=3, AVERAGE($A1:$C1), IF(COUNT($A1:$D1)=3, AVERAGE($A1:$D1), IF(COUNT($A1:$E1)=3, AVERAGE($A1:$E1), IF(COUNT($A1:$F1)=3, AVERAGE($A1:$F1), IF(COUNT($A1:$G1)=3, AVERAGE($A1:$G1),"oops")))))
```

which looks for the shortest initial subset of the row
that contains three numbers, and averages that. 
This becomes not only awkward for large numbers of columns,
but may actually fail fairly quickly,
as (I believe) `IF()` has a fairly low nesting limit.

## Solution 1.9

Finesse.

I call this “1.9” because it’s not done yet. 
The expression

```
SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER($A1:$G1),COLUMN($A1:$G1),""), {1,2,3})
```

(used in an array formula)
finds the column numbers of the first three numbers on row 1. 
The

```
IF(ISNUMBER($A1:$G1),COLUMN($A1:$G1),"")
```

part evaluates to

```
IF( {TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, "" )
```

which reduces to

```
{ 1, "", 3, "", 5, 6, 7 }
```

and `SMALL(…, {1,2,3})` of the above produces `{ 1, 3, 5 }`. 
It should be a simple matter of saying

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX($A7:$G7, 1, SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER($A7:$G7),COLUMN($A7:$G7),""),{1,2,3})))
```

or

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($A7:$G7, 1, SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER($A7:$G7),COLUMN($A7:$G7),""),{1,2,3})))
```

but they return either the value of `A1` (12) or an error
(`#DIV/0!` or `#REF!`).  I can’t figure out how to finish this.